# sticky nav bar - to appear on mobile but sticky on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

At the moment - I have a sticky nav bar that slowly fades it after certain section has been scrolled.

```
var $logo = jQuery('#teavanaheader-sticky-wrapper');
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop()> 250) {   
        //alert("scop");
        jQuery('#teavanaheader-sticky-wrapper').fadeIn( "slow" );
    }else {
        jQuery('#teavanaheader-sticky-wrapper').slideUp();
    }

});
```

How can I make it to appear straightaway when user is on mobile devices. So on desktop it will fade in slowly like how it is now but on mobile sizes it will appear straightaway?

Answer (score 0):

Use this JS.

https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile

isMobile detects if it is a phone,tablet,etc that accessed it. Now upon true, just dont fade in.

**SAMPLE**

```
<script>
if (isMobile.apple.phone || isMobile.android.phone || isMobile.seven_inch) 
{
    //Just appear
}
else
{
    //Fade in, etc
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried doing this but didn't work:  if (isMobile.apple.phone || isMobile.android.phone || isMobile.seven_inch) 
   {
       jQuery('#teavanaheader-sticky-wrapper').show();
   }
   else
   {
     jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
     if(jQuery(this).scrollTop()> 250)
     {   //alert("scop");
     //  $logo.css({display: $(this).scrollTop() > 100? "block":"none"});
      jQuery('#teavanaheader-sticky-wrapper').fadeIn( "slow" );
     }else{
       jQuery('#teavanaheader-sticky-wrapper').slideUp();
     }

    });
   }

Comment: Can you pres f12 and look at the config? Just to see if you have put the js file and it's working. It might not have been imported.

Comment: I imported it. but it appears but then disappeared. (I also have a seperate js for my navigation - http://54.169.61.153/js/teavana/navigation.js ) not sure if anything there overwrite the function